# Using OpenID (RPX) (and maybe OAuth) for a RESTful web service

Tags: javascript, rest, openid, spring-security, restful-authentication

How would you combine OpenID with a RESTful web service?

The personal project I'm working on is using the RPX SaaS to do OpenID. The key result of this is URL describing the logged in user. The app itself is heavily Javascript and I'm planning on using a REST api to communicate with the backend for database persistence and spatial processing.

The security requirements on this application aren't big. I want to know which user is making a request. I don't believe I need to use SSL to be confidential about the data and I don't want the overhead of running SSL.

I'm using Spring and would like to use Spring Security (Acegi) if possible but I'm not wedded to that idea.

Options:

1. Return the OpenID URL to the Javascript app, use this to retrieve the list of resources for the user and then retrieve/save/etc those resources by id.
2. Create a session table which connects the OpenID URL with a random session token. Return the token to the Javascript app which must then return the token with every subsequent request.
3. Use the session from option 2 as the Consumer Token, etc for OAuth. Initially, the session would be sent to the app using PKI encryption.
4. Rely on J2EE HTTP Session.

Of these options I'm leaning towards option 2. Hijacking the session would be difficult as the attacker would have to guess the session id and I don't believe the application requires protection from sniffing. Option 3 is essentially the same as option 2 but the session id isn't available for sniffing. Option 4 puts the OpenID URL into the server's memory and causes all the scalability problems REST is designed to avoid.

I'm grateful for any discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

So, 2 years 3 months later I can answer my own question. I implemented this for my personal project and I have separately implemented it for my employer.

Plugging into Spring Security is the best way to go. You can choose to use the pre-authenticated flow but you may find the `CasAuthenticationFilter` (and `CasAuthenticationEntryPoint`) work better as they have most of the flow you need.